# Apps Scripts within Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

So I might be doing this entirely wrong, but I am trying to create a slideshow based on images stored in a google drive folder that can be easily added (ie by a non-technical person) to a google site.

I created a script that outputs the slideshow using the HTMLService.  You can view the working site at https://script.google.com/a/macros/needham.k12.ma.us/s/AKfycbyOyqTr_sEMWRVBn0e0r4NV5083_LwzZSMYwPU-25_xd2m6ZexS/exec?width=300&height=200&folderID=0B-6QUsY0bQG5ZmI4QTl4T1ZQZmc

When I try to insert this script into a google site using the Apps Script Gadget  (Screenshot 1) using the link above it appears that the parameters are either lost or ignored (Screenshot 2).  When I hard code the parameters into the script, the slideshow loads correctly (Screenshot 3).

**Screenshot 1**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2**

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Screenshot 3**

[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the parameters to the URL when inserting your script in a Google Site. However, you can pass the parameters to the Site URL utself and the script will pick it up. 
For example, 
http://sites.google.com/example.com/example-site/example-page?folderID=1235

As for the width and the height, you can adjust them when you insert the script into a Site using controls that Google Sites provides

Comment: Wow.  Never would have thought about doing it that way.  Unfortunatley this means that I could not have more than 1 slideshow on a page and that all links to the slide show would have to include the correct parameters.

Is there any other way to get this work?  I thought about using iFrames, but those appear to have stopped working in the last few weeks.  I also thought about creating a gadget with parameters, but I am not sure if that will work.

Comment: Yes, you're out of luck if you want to include multiple parameters. However, if it is an option for you depending on your use-case, you can have an initial screen asking for the folder id and remember it and use it for future invocations of the script

Comment: Interesting idea... I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. My solution was to write a google gadget that iframed my apps script and added fhe necesary parameters.

Comment: Is this still working for you?  I was planning on using iframes originally, but I started having trouble with them in Google Sites about a month ago.

Comment: I didnt use the public iframe gadget, I made my own which corrected http/https issues.